# springmvc-router configuration assistance required

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I followed this tutorial http://resthub.github.io/springmvc-router/ to achieve spring routing using a `routes.conf` file. Using the code below

```
// Configuration code as mentioned in tutorial
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.resthub.web.springmvc.router.RouterConfigurationSupport;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "my base pack")
// You should not use the @EnableWebMvc annotation
public class WebAppConfig extends RouterConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public List<String> listRouteFiles() {

        List<String> routeFiles = new ArrayList<String>();

        routeFiles.add("routes.conf");

        return routeFiles;
    }
}
```

`routes.conf` is placed under `src\main\resources`

springmvc-router is not picking `routes.conf` file

I'm getting a following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'handlerMapping' defined in ServletContext   
resource [/WEB-INF/axpense-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;

nested exception is org.resthub.web.springmvc.router.exceptions.RouteFileParsingException:
Could not read route configuration files; 

nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
Could not open ServletContext resource [/routes.conf] at 
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
```

Comment: Put it in `src/main/webapp/` or prefix with `classpath:`.

Answer (score 0):

simply replace the line  routeFiles.add("routes.conf");
with routeFile.add(classpath:/routes.conf); // worked for me